# Mongodb split substrings for entries matching certain condition

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection which consists of such entries:

```
{
        "_id" : "85f4f64e-1c50-4a3c-a2bf-72bc5fba7eca",
        "properties" : {
                "property1" : "AB12345",
                "property2" : "XXXXXX"
        },
        "otherproperties" : [
                {
                        "Name" : "John",
                        "Time" : 1436,
                        "Count" : 5041


 }
```

I need to find the ones where otherproperties exists and is not []

But I also need at the same time property1 split in two substrings

```
"property0" : "AB"
"property1" : "12345"
```

What I wish to achieve is roughly below SQL statement for mongodb

```
select substr(property1,0,2) , substr(property1,2,5), property2 from mycollection where otherproperties !=''
```

I would prefer single query because afterwards I need to export result in CSV using this query as filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. The first stage in the pipeline is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage where you select only those sub-documents where "otherproperties" [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists). The next and last stage is the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) stage where you use the [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) operator a substring of a string.

```js
db.mycollection.aggregate([ 
    { '$match': { 'otherproperties.0': { '$exists': true } } },
    { '$project': { 
        'subproperty1_1': { '$substr': [ '$properties.property1', 0, 2 ] },
        'subproperty1_2': { '$substr': [ '$properties.property1', 2, 5 ] },
        'property2': '$properties.property2'
    }}
])
```

Which yields:

```js
{
        "_id" : "85f4f64e-1c50-4a3c-a2bf-72bc5fba7eca",
        "subproperty1_1" : "AB",
        "subproperty1_2" : "12345",
        "property2" : "XXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$substr` in mongodb

```
{ $substr: [ <string>, <start>, <length> ] }
```

Ex :

```
property0: { $substr: [ "$property1", 0, 2 ] }
```